# why isn't <img [src]> not showing inside of <ion col> with *ngFor loop?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have some code that's intended to show a user profile image, either the default one or the users uploaded picture. Now, the img [src]="profileImage" 
 shows the image perfectly fine on its own. However when I put it inside the ion-col, it does not show.

Below is the following code I am working with

HTML

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let item of students" >
     <div  class= "imageHold" >
         <img [src]= "profileImage"> 
     </div>
 </ion-col>
```

TS

```
export class EditProfilePage implements OnInit {



  profileImage : any;

  ngOnInit() {
  this.profileImage =  ["./assets/imgs/user.png"]

this.students = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          userName: e.payload.doc.data()['userName'],
          userBio: e.payload.doc.data()['userBio'],
          profileImage: e.payload.doc.data()['profileImage'],
        };
      })
      console.log(this.students);

    }
```

firebase code snippet to upload profile image

```
  this.firebaseService.uploadImage(image_src, randomId)
    .then(photoURL => {
      this.profileImage = photoURL;
      loading.dismiss();
      toast.present();
```

Comment: is it inside `ion-row` ?

Comment: Have you tried with `<img [src]= "item.profileImage">`?

Comment: yes, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have profileImage as String array, and [src] accept only string

try like this

```js
this.profileImage =  "./assets/imgs/user.png"; //don't declare this as string
```

or if you have multiple images then try to get with index

```js
this.profileImage =  ["./assets/imgs/user.png","./assets/imgs/user1.png"]
```

in html

```html
 <img [src]= "profileImage[0]">
```